# Creating an enum in Swift, exportable to ObjC, based on another enum: String

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I have an `enum Foo: String` in Swift (therefore not exportable to Objective-C) and I'm trying to create another enum `FooObjc` in Swift to kinda "wrap" the existent one so that it is 1) available to use in Objective-C and 2) convertable back and forth (`Foo` <=> `FooObjc`). The original `Foo` enum is part of a framework that I don't want to modify. Of course, it's very easy to do what I want if I use a class instead, like this:

```
@objc public class FooObjc: NSObject {
    public private(set) var foo: Foo
    @objc public var string: String {
        return foo.rawValue
    }

    @objc public init?(string: NSString) {
        guard let foo = Foo(rawValue: string as String) else {
            return nil
        }
        self.foo = foo
    }

    internal init(foo: Foo) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
}
```

(PS: not able to inherit from `NSString` because the Swift compiler still doesn't accept creating initializers for that class)

Ok, but I definitely don't like this approach because then my Objective-C code will be string-typed. I really want to use an `enum` instead because after all, that's what it is. This is the least bad working version I could get:

```
@objc public enum FooObjc: Int, RawRepresentable {
    case undefined = -1
    case bar
    case baz
    // omitting many more cases

    internal init?(_ foo: Foo?) {
        if let foo = foo {
            self = fooMapping.filter { $1 == foo }.map { $0.key }.first!
        } else {
            self = .undefined
        }
    }

    // MARK: - RawRepresentable

    public typealias RawValue = String

    public init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
        let filter = fooMapping.filter { $1?.rawValue == rawValue }
        guard filter.count > 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        self = filter.map { $0.key }.first!
    }

    public var rawValue: RawValue {
        switch (self) {
        case .undefined: return "undefined"
        case .bar: return Foo.bar.rawValue
        case .baz: return Foo.baz.rawValue
        // omitting many more cases
        }
    }
}

private let fooMapping: [FooObjc: Foo?] = [
    .undefined : nil,
    .bar : .bar,
    .baz : .baz
    // omitting many more cases
]
```

Notice that:

1. the `fooMapping` is useful to avoid one switch-case for each initializer
2. this `undefined` case was necessary because in Swift you can have optional `enum` properties, in Objective-C you can't, so this case will directly map to a `Foo?` which value is `nil`.

What worries me here is that I had to write the same cases from the original Foo **three** times... I'm completely satisfied if I repeat it only twice, but I wasn't able to use the `fooMapping` in the `rawValue` property because then I get a cycle between these two.

Note: I'm not sure if this is relevant to the question, but in the original `enum`, some of the cases have special String attributions, e.g. we have simply `case bar` but we also have `case baz = "something"`.

So, the question is: does anyone have suggestions to improve this approach or even suggest something completely new that would avoid so much code repetition?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What worries me here is that I had to write the same cases from the original Foo three times

Consider an array `["bar", "baz" ...]`. By looking at the index of a string in this array and making the necessary adjustments, you can translate from a string to an integer (and thence, via raw value, to a case). By indexing into the array and making the necessary adjustments, you can translate from an integer to a string (and thence, via raw value, to a case). So you will only have to write out the string values once. This eliminates two of your repetitions.

You will still have to write out the case names in the enum declaration, because there's no other way to tell Objective-C the names of the cases. The way to eliminate *that* repetition, obviously, is to be willing to change the implementation of Foo itself so that *it* becomes Objective-C-compatible. But you have stated up front that you refuse to do that, so now you must pay the price.

Comment: Thank you @matt, yes what you say in the second paragraph is the exact reason why I said "I'm completely satisfied if I repeat it only twice", as I'm counting my own enum cases declaration as one already. Your approach seems a very good idea, I'll try it out and accept the answer soon :) upvoting right now.

Comment: If the situation had been more complicated we could still have solved it with an array of tuples or other pairs uniting a string and its corresponding integer. But there seems to be no need for that; the index number in the array will do.